# How to implement nested groups in Db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

Question:
In our database, we have a table Users, a table Groups, and a mapping table from users to groups.
Then we have permissions, which are on Groups.

```
T_User
USR_UID
USR_Name
USR_PasswordHash


T_Group
GRP_UID
GRP_Name


T_MAP_User_Group
MAP_USRGRP_UID
MAP_USRGRP_USR_UID
MAP_USRGRP_GRP_UID


T_MAP_SitePermission
MAP_STEGRP_UID
MAP_STEGRP_STE_UID
MAP_STEGRP_GRP_UID
MAP_STEGRP_ReadPermission
MAP_STEGRP_WritePermission
MAP_STEGRP_DeletePermission


T_Sites
STE_UID
STE_Name
STE_Location
```

Now if I wanted to add a Group to a Group (nested groups, as in ActiveDirectory), how would I go about implementing this, especially resolving users to groups and rights/permisssions in a select query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mapping table for groups... following your convention, it would look something like the following:

```
T_MAP_Group_Group
MAP_GRPGRP_UID
MAP_GRPGRP_PARENT_GRP_UID
MAP_GRPGRP_CHILD_GRP_UID
```

This allows for a group to be nested within multiple parent groups... and at the same time allows for a group to be the parent of multiple children groups.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to handle this problem, I believe the best way to handle it would be to create a Parent Group to Group relationship table.  As to how would right a query to determine the permissions I don't think there is enough information to determine that yet.  How would conflicting permission be resolved, would the parent group override the child or the other way around?